# How to require a package installed via Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, package, packagist

I installed `emanueleminotto/simple-html-dom` via `composer`.

How can I use classes from the package without getting an error?

**Note**: I use XAMPP to run PHP scripts.

Error Message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'simple_html_dom' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\PHP\scrape_1.php:3
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\PHP\scrape_1.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'simple_html_dom' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\PHP\scrape_1.php:3
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\PHP\scrape_1.php on line 3

Comment: which error you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running

```
$ composer install
```

require the autoloader generated in `vendor/autoload.php` at the top of your script file (or, for a web application, in the front controller).

Then you will have all autoloaded classes available in your script.

```
<?php    

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$htmlDom = new simple_html_dom_node();
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading.

Answer (score 1):

apparently `emanueleminotto/simple-html-dom` doesn't use a namespace so by default uses the global namespace. the clean solution would be to include the `vendor/autoload.php` (created/generated/updated by composer) and use the classes/functions by prepending `\`, to indicate the global namespace ... unless you work in the global namespace yourself, in  which case you don't have to prepend.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use them. If I see that right, the whole package is really only one file which is autoloader by composer.

If you include the `vendor/autoload.php` file in your PHP Script, you should be good to go with the classes in the package.